# Does anyone know what enable contact to business unit mapping does in Marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I can't find any real documentation on this feature.. the help pages just tell you how to enable it, without giving any context

[image: Account settings]

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_contact_to_business_unit_mapping_activity.htm&type=5
This article here does seem to explain it quite clearly. I haven't used this feature myself but if you have a specific use case or question maybe someone else can answer it?